# How to query a Google BigQuery table and remove duplicates based on a subset of columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that joins two google tables and produces a table with 6 columns (`a`, `b`,  `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`). Next, I move that table to a google bucket and then download that google bucket to a bunch of CSV's. Finally I insert those CVS's into a `postgres` database table which has 2 primary keys, `a` and `b`.

The problem is that there is no primary key in the google table and some of the rows have just one value different, so I need to produce a query result that is has no duplicates in `a` and `b`. I have tried the following...

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT A.a,
           A.b,
           A.c AS c, 
           A.d AS d,
           B.c AS e,
           B.d AS f
FROM
  `my_proj.my_table_A` A
FULL OUTER JOIN
  `my_proj.my_table_B` B
ON
  A.a = B.a
  AND A.b = B.b
```

...but it will still allow `a` and `b` to have duplicates if, for example, `f` is different. I only need one of the duplicate rows and it does not matter which one.

How do I only remove duplicates based only on `a` and `b`?

Comment: What is supposed to happen with the different `f` values if you are only deduplicating based on `a` and `b`? Are you just going to drop one of them?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard, Yes, just drop one of them, because I only need one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with `ANY_VALUE`:

```
SELECT
  A.a,
  A.b,
  ANY_VALUE(A.c) AS c, 
  ANY_VALUE(A.d) AS d,
  ANY_VALUE(B.c) AS e,
  ANY_VALUE(B.d) AS f
FROM
  `my_proj.my_table_A` A
FULL OUTER JOIN
  `my_proj.my_table_B` B
ON
  A.a = B.a
  AND A.b = B.b
GROUP BY
  A.a,
  A.b
```

Comment: This might work but `BigQuery` terminates the job and requests permission to do "big jobs", which I wouldn't like to give. I think the way for me to go is to de-duplicate the tables and then run my queries over them. This is probably a separate question, but do you know how to de-duplicate a table based on only two columns, like `a` and `b`?

Comment: I don't know what "big jobs" means. This answer already shows how to deduplicate based on `a` and `b`...just use `GROUP BY` with `ANY_VALUE`, and you can apply this pattern to a single table as well.

Comment: By "big jobs" I meant that I got the error `Error: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. GROUP BY operator used too much memory`, so I need a way without using the `GROUP BY` clause